# How to deal with nested forms?(ERROR: mechanize._form.ParseError: nested FORMs)

Tags: python, mechanize

I'm trying to submit a form in a website and when I run the code, it gives me the error:

> mechanize._form.ParseError: nested FORMs

So I checked and in the website, there are 2 forms that are inside each other.
the form that I need, which is the first one, is closed properly.

Is there anyway to deal with that?

Answer (score 0):

```
br.select_form(name = "frmName") if name of the form is stated, otherwise
br.select_form(nr=0) which means you are accessing the first form with index 0(nr=0)
```

Comment: the form i need doesnt has a name, only id.
i use this code to  call the exact form i want:
"def select_form(form):
return form.attrs.get('id', None) == 'email-form'
br.select_form(predicate=select_form)"
but still i get the neseted forms error

Answer (score 0):

br.select_form(predicate=lambda f: f.attrs.get('id', None) == 'email-form')
This may help you in your function for selecting the form..